# youtube-api - check if youtube account verified?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How to know if via youtube API if youtube account is verified or not?

i'm meaning the verification found on this link: https://www.youtube.com/verify

I DON'T mean the blue badge, i mean the account verification via phone number or email address that can be found on the above address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a field for knowing if the youtube channel is verified from the Youtube API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484816/is-there-a-field-for-knowing-if-the-youtube-channel-is-verified-from-the-youtube)

Comment: Thanks, no i'm not asking about the verified channel "blue badge", i want the account verification with phone number and email, as here: https://www.youtube.com/verify

Comment: Were you able to find anything?

Comment: No, it was a long time ago. I gave up.