# Check if a youtube account is verified ahead of time or if an account has permissions to set a custom thumbnail

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to tell if a YouTube account is verified or not?
(Not the blue badge,  I mean the account verification via phone number)

I'm currently using the PHP Client.

I need this to check if they have permissions to post Youtube custom thumbnails ahead of time.  So if the above isn't possible, any ideas on how to check ahead of time is appreciated.

I have the same question as [youtube-api - check if youtube account verified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211468/youtube-api-check-if-youtube-account-verified) but noticed that there wasn't much activity or an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a channels.list get back a list of  [channel resources](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource)  this contains a filed called longUploadsStatus which i believe is the same as the one that gives you the permission to upload thumbnails.

[image]