# How do I know if a channel is a verification using the YouTube Data API?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need a little help with YouTube Data API.

Please tell me how I can find out whether the channel is [verification](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3046484?hl=en) using the API.
As far as I understand, I need to look at

> youtube.channels.list

but could not find where exactly.

for example: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails%252C+statistics%252Cstatus&id=UCz24srq31kr8CyNT-oN1Dqw&_h=13&

---

**UPDATED:** If I correctly understood this possibility yet. Guys from Google have set 'status Assigned' and mark task for this as a feature request.
Perhaps in the future, we will have such an opportunity.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62275991

Comment: Are you asking for a [way to check for the verification badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484816/is-there-a-field-for-knowing-if-the-youtube-channel-is-verified-from-the-youtube)?

Comment: Thank @noogui. As far I understand at the moment there is no such possibility.
Except that manually parsing the HTML page of the channel.